# An Exception method, which logs and throw the exception, which is coming as parameter

Tags: java, exception

I have an Util class and in this class, I am trying to implement a simple method, which logs the coming message and throw the sent exception. For a (possibly) simple reason, I could not achieve it.

My current method looks like that;

```
 public static void handleException( Exception exception, String errorMessage )
  {
    LOGGER.error( errorMessage + "\n " + exception.getMessage() );
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( errorMessage + "\n " + aException.getMessage() );
  }
```

However, I would like not only IllegalArgumentException, but the type of the exception, which is sent as parameter (a.k.a exception).

```
 public static void handleException( FooException exception, String errorMessage )
  {
    LOGGER.error( errorMessage + "\n " + exception.getMessage() );
    throw new FooException( errorMessage + "\n " + aException.getMessage() );
  }
```

Which way would be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Exceptions and not simply throw the one you already got as parameter?

Comment: @ArcticLord I just want to centralize the exception handling in a Util class. I do not like *throw exceptions* all over the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a type parameter to the method, and then rethrow the original exception:

```
public static <T extends Exception> void handleException(
    T exception,
    String errorMessage
    ) throws T
{
    LOGGER.error( errorMessage + "\n " + exception.getMessage() );
    throw exception;
}
```

You won't be able to change its message, though.

To change its message, you'd have to construct a new one, which means you'd have to know what arguments its constructor takes. Most `Exception` subclasses accept a message string and "cause" exception, but by no means all. Still, if we make that assumption:

```
public static <T extends Exception> void handleException(
    T exception,
    String errorMessage
    ) throws T
{
    final String newMessage = errorMessage + "\n " + exception.getMessage();
    LOGGER.error(newMessage);
    T newException = exception;
    try {
        newException = (T)exception.getClass()
                                .getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class, Exception.class })
                                .newInstance(new Object[] { newMessage, exception});
    } catch (Exception) {
    }
    throw newException;
}
```

Or something along those lines...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just rethrow the exception you got in the first place?

throw exception;

If this doesn't match your requirements, you could try to create a new instance by getting the class from your exception and using reflection (could go wrong because there might be diffrent constructors)

Hope it helps

Comment: I just want to centralize the exception handling in a place. Instead of writing logging and throwing exception all over the code, in a method, i found it more logical.